# Delete items from LongListMultiSelector

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, inotifycollectionchanged

I'm new to Windows Phone 8 development. I've been working with it for about a month now and have written my own news app consuming data from an API. I save article content offline into the app's local storage as .json files. Since I have already them saved offline I want to give my users the ability to 'save' that article to a list of favourites and have one of my pivot items show the list of saved articles for them to access later. I also want that list manageable by the user i.e. I want them to be able to delete the items as necessary.

I'm planning on loading the data context for the list using an object called:

```
SavedArticles
```

which is simply a

```
List<Article>
```

I've read a lot about how to update the current view using *INotifyPropertyChanged*, but I think that is more about updating properties of existing items in the list. What I need is something that can update the ItemsSource after the user selects an item and then clicks delete in the AppBar. I *think* that is where *INotifyCollectionChanged* should come in, but for the life of me, I can't see how to implement it.

Looking for someone to enlighten me or point me at a great example.

I have Googled this to death but cannot find many examples and the ones I have seen, I'm just not getting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `List<Article>` use an `ObservableCollection<Article>` (from `System.Collections.ObjectModel`) as this implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.
This means that when you remove an item from the underlying collection (which is what your delete function should do) then this will be reflected in the databound UI collection.